# How can I declare a date variable and insert the value from a datetimepicker into my database?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Previously, I was using just the datepicker function from bootstrap to insert a date value on a form that will get submitted to the database.

Now, I've changed to "Tempo Dominus Bootstrap 4" since it has some interesting functions I might want to use in the future.

Here's what I have currently done.

**HTML for the date input**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Date</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="shiftDate" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Script to set the minDate to now**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
            minDate: moment()
        });
</script>
```

**Now this was how I was inserting the date when I didn't have the time included and it was working**

```
$date=strtotime($_POST['date']);
$date=date("Y-m-d",$date);
```

Any help for the declaration is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a datetime picker so your date has hour, minutes & seconds so you need to create the date based on the new format

```
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$date);
```

Also make sure you name your input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" name="date" id="shiftDate" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks sir! Silly me forgot both of these!

Comment: happens to the best of us:)